# Biblatex: define custom style or modify existing?

Tags: biblatex, citing

The style I need citations in seems so far removed from the provided Biblatex styles that I'm unsure whether it's best to extensively modify an existing style or write a custom one; and not too sure how exactly to go about doing either. Full citations are to go in footnotes; no bibliography. *Ibid.* to be used where appropriate, but not op cit. Here is what I need:

ARTICLE:

First mention:

> Allen Carlson, `Nature and Positive Aesthetics’, *Environmental Ethics* 6 (1984), 5–34, at 33–4.

Subsequent (if not *Ibid.*):

> Carlson, `Nature and Positive Aesthetics’, 33-4.

(NB: only volume, no number)

BOOK:

First mention:

> Donald Worster, *Nature’s Economy: A History of Ecological Ideas* (2nd edn, Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, 1994), 471.

Subsequent:

> Worster, *Nature’s Economy*, 19–38.

INBOOK and INCOLLECTION:

First mention:

> Charles Shah Pittendrigh, `Adaption, Natural Selection, and Behavior’, in Anne Roe and George Simpson (eds), *Behavior and Evolution* (New Haven: Yale University Press, 1958), 390–416, at 400.

Subsequent:

> Pittendrigh, `Adaption, Natural Selection, and Behavior’, 392.

Advice gratefully received!

EDITS:

Additions:

Document MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bibstyle=verbose-ibid, citestyle=BJA,
usetranslator=true, ibidpage=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{natural_aesthetics.bib}
\begin{document}
\footcite[37]{Godlovitch1994}
\footcite[37]{HumeSOT}
\footcite[37]{berleant2005}
\footcite[37]{Carroll1993}
\footcite[37]{Godlovitch1994}
\footcite[37]{HumeSOT}
\footcite[37]{berleant2005}
\footcite[37]{Carroll1993}
\end{document}
```

MWE bib file:

```
@BOOK{Berleant2005,
title = {Aesthetics and Environment},
publisher = {Ashgate},
year = {2005},
author = {Arnold Berleant},
location = {Aldershot}
}
@INCOLLECTION{Carroll1993,
author = {Noel Carroll},
title = {On Being Moved By Nature: Between Religion and Natural History},
booktitle = {Landscape, Natural Beauty and the Arts},
publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
year = {1993},
editor = {Salim Kemal and Ivan Gaskell},
pages = {244-266},
location = {Cambridge}
}
@INBOOK{HumeSOT,
pages = {134--149},
title = {Of The Standard of Taste},
publisher = {Ward, Lock and Bowden},
year = {1875},
author = {David Hume},
bookauthor = {David Hume},
booktitle = {Essays Literary, Moral, and Political},
location = {London}
}
@ARTICLE{Godlovitch1994,
author = {Stan Godlovitch},
title = {Icebreakers: Environmentalism and Natural Aesthetics},
journal = {Journal of Applied Philosophy},
year = {1994},
volume = {11},
pages = {15-30},
number = {1}
}
```

BJA.cbx in process of modification: took the advice to append things to verbose-ibid.cbx : my additions and requests at end.

```
% $Id: BJA.cbx,v 1.0 $

\ProvidesFile{BJA.cbx}
[\abx@cbxid $Id: BJA.cbx, v 1.0 $]

\RequireCitationStyle{verbose-ibid}

\AtEveryCitekey{
  \clearfield{number}} %removes journal number for articles

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{%
  \printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}} % removes in for articles


\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{at #1}% replaces p and pp with at in page refs
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{at #1}% replaces p and pp with at
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1} %omits pp in article etc
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space} %comma space between units

%for book: put (edition, location: publisher, year)

%for article, inbook, incollection: single quotes round titles

% for inbook, incollection: editors names (eds), title, (edition, location: publisher, year)

% for inbook, incollection: no punctuation after in


\endinput
```

Comment: Does [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/10119) help? I would recommend you try to find the style that is closest to your needs then either copy the files, rename them and modify them, or create a new style that eventually loads an existing one in order to ease your work. Someone here can help you crafting the style either way, but [it would be easier with a MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/10119)

Comment: This is basically the `verbose-ibid` style, with `ibidpage=true`, plus some modifications of the full citation style (mainly putting parentheses around the publication information).

Comment: Ah, OK -- I had (a) not spotted that previous answer, and (b) not spotted the verbose-ibid style. I'll go away and try it all out, and come back with a MWE if have any trouble. Thanks for your quick help.

Comment: But it's a bit more complicated than that, since there are a number of differences between your full citations and the standard biblatex ones.  So this is not a fast fix.  It would make sense to make your own `.cbx` file which loads `verbose-ibid` and then modifies all the rest.

Comment: This looks very much like `biblatex-chicago` except with british style quotation marks, which would not be hard to change.  Maybe adding the edition in parenthesis would need to be tweaked, too, but one needs a fuller spec before making those kind of changes.  Can you point to an example bibliography or stylesheet somewhere?

Comment: @Nick What we mean by an example is a document we can just copy-paste and modify in order to give you an answer. The example of what you want to end up with seems clear enough to me, but we want to see a sample of what you have (minimal document/code and bibliography file) so we can find and solve the problems more easily while using stuff that will fit exactly with your project (and it is faster for everyone to just copy-paste, which isn't unfair).

Comment: AH, OK. See edits above...

Comment: Thank you! I am editing your MWE to correct the following: we don't have a BJA bibstyle, so no need to load it; there's an extra comma in the Hume entry; we can just load `verbose-ibid` instead of copying it entirely.

Comment: Thanks! Last thing especially neat to know I'll continue tinkering if I get a chance and let you all know if I sort things out myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here, I think this should do more or less what you want (you may find some issues when you add new items with different fields… always happens). A couple of things you may be interested in:

- You can load the package with `autocite=footnote` and add `\let\cite=\autocite` to your preamble, so that `\cite` will automatically put your citations in footnotes (unless you are already in one).
- I loaded `babel` and `csquotes` with `british` language to get you the single quotes you need; I know of no other proper way to do it.
- You still need to copy and modify `english.lbx` and change the shorthands for "edition" and "editor"/"editors". These changes can't be done in the preamble.

Now, add this to your preamble:

```
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
```

And you can copy this to your style file:

```
% $Id: BJA.cbx,v 1.0 $

\ProvidesFile{BJA.cbx}
[\abx@cbxid $Id: BJA.cbx, v 1.0 $]

\RequireCitationStyle{verbose-ibid}

% Remove journal number for articles
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {\clearfield{number}}
    {}}

% Delete pagination in postnote (p., etc.) — No idea why I had to do this for it to work
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifciteseen
    {\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}%
      \DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}}
    {\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{at #1}%
      \DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{at #1}}}

% Remove "in" for articles
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\nopunct\addspace}}}

% Don't italicise title
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{maintitle}{#1}

% Don't italicise journal title
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}

% Cite "eds." in parentheses
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

% Omit "p." indicator
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

% Use comma and space between units
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

% Book Customisation

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \space\nopunct
  \mkbibparens{%
    \setunit{\unspace}\newblock
    \iffieldundef{edition}
      {}
      {\printfield{edition}%
        \newunit}
    \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}}
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

% Inbook Customisation

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inbook}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}}
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \space\nopunct
  \mkbibparens{%
    \setunit{\unspace}\newblock
    \iffieldundef{edition}
      {}
      {\printfield{edition}%
        \newunit}
    \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}}
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

% Incollection Customisation

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}
     \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}}
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \space\nopunct
  \mkbibparens{%
    \setunit{\unspace}\newblock
    \iffieldundef{edition}
      {}
      {\printfield{edition}%
        \newunit}
    \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}}
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

% For "edition"="edn", modify a copy of english.lbx
% Same goes for "eds" without a dot

\endinput
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Did I miss anything?

**EDIT**: Corrected the book and collection/inbook titles that appeared in italics. They are now in roman (but I didn't re-upload the picture).

Comment: Didn't miss a thing -- thanks so much! As it happens, I wanted the journal, book, and collection titles in italics (as per examples at the top), but I can easily see how to do that from your code, or rather what not to copy. Thanks!