# Biblatex AMA style

Tags: biblatex

I'm counting on the fact that somebody must have done this and has a style file for biblatex-AMA (American Medical Association). Otherwise how do I make the list of references look like this:

> Heibel AK, Vergeldt FJ, van As H, Kapteijn F, Moulijn J, Boger T. Gas
>   and liquid distribution in the monolith film flow reactor. AIChE Journal. 2003;49:3007-3017.

Comment: Could you post a minimal example of what you obtain now and give some details of how it should be corrected? B.t.w., I suppose you mean biblatex-`APA`.

Comment: A google search reveals no `biblatex-ama` style and from what you have posted it is not really easy to make out what it would look like, but it looks quite close to any of the standard styles with the `in` macro chucked away, `terseints` option, and some weird stuff going on in the `volume`/`pages` department.

Comment: @Bernard No, I mean the AMA style (American Medical Association). biblatex-ama does not exist on CTAN but I thought somebody must have done it at some point as a personal style file (and would like to share).

Comment: I see. The simplest (?) would be to start from an existing style file close to what you want and patch with a package such as `xpatch`, which is done for that.

Comment: There is a `ama.bst` (I suppose you know that) and is hazard the guess that the style is not so common outside AMA publications, so it is not very likely that someone has gone through the ordeal of creating, publishing and maintaining (!) a `biblatex` style for that. If you insist on `biblatex`, your best bet is to find a standard style that comes closest to what you need ([here are examples of all the standard styles](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples)), and then identify what bits you need changed.

Comment: You might want to read [this nice essay (or non-essay) by Paul Stanley](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80047/35864) on modifying `biblatex` styles to meet ones needs (have a look at the linked questions to that question as well).

Comment: A very similar style seems to be asked for in [Biblatex citation style ASM](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/156094/35864).

Comment: I'm inclined to vote to close this as *too broad* or *unclear what you're asking*. As this question currently stands it is not very likely to attract a constructive answer (the answer to your first question is "no", while the "otherwise" question is not clear enough and does not provide enough detail to be answered).

Comment: @moewe I managed to create the style. I started from the standard authoryear and patched some commands.

Comment: Aha! In that case why not answer this question yourself, so future AMA writers might benefit from it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a fix. I tested it only on articles and books:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, bibstyle=authortitle, natbib=true, maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=99, isbn=false, url=false, firstinits=true, uniquename=false, uniquelist=false, terseinits]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{{#1\isdot}}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon}

% Normal title font (remove italic)
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1\addperiod}
\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{{#1}}

% Year after title
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
    \usebibmacro{journal}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
        \printfield{series}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}%
    \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
    \setunit{\addsemicolon\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
    \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
    \usebibmacro{issue}%
    \newunit%
}

% Print only the year
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
    \printfield{year}%
}

% Remove "and" from list of authors
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}
```

[image]

Comment: Your way to display the year after the title seems rather crude to me, why not use `bibstyle=authoritle` instead?

Comment: @moewe authortitle makes the year appear after volume number. It should be before... I'll try to patch it.

Comment: I see, have a look at `journal+issuetitle` as defined in `standard.bbx` (line 744 in my version) and swap `\usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}` and `\usebibmacro{issue+date}` (changing punctuation between them accoding to your taste) - for that to work you should then get rid of the `\renewbibmacro*{date}{}` line (we want to see the date after all).

Comment: @moewe I made an update.

Comment: While we're at it, I would prefer `\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}` over `\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{, }`. You need to be careful with redefining `issue+date` as you did because you might run into troubles with `extradate` disambiguation.

Comment: @moewe Should I xpatch the command to get the issue+date before volume number?

Comment: What is wrong with `\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \printfield{issue}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}` (modulo line breaks, sorry)? Then there is no need to `xpatch` any macros (I think). (BTW: a full MWE would be appreciated, so people can test your solution here.)

Comment: `\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{{#1}.}` might cause double punctuation in some cases (when journals - or jounral abbreviations - end in a dot), so `\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1\addperiod}` is probably preferrable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22008/discussion-between-remus-and-moewe).

Comment: Thanks for your work @remus! I changed some details to match the style of the _American Journal of Transplantation_ and [created a gist](https://gist.github.com/thetapper/b8a6e5bb5f6676a7ab0b669f11ec1689).

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[super,sort&compress]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{comma,numbers,super,open={},close={}} 
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section*{Latex Superscript Citation (AMA-like)}

This is a superscript citation~\citep{da2018graph}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
    \bibitem{da2018graph}
    Silva WMC, Wercelens P, Walter MEM et~al.
    \newblock Graph databases in molecular biology.
    \newblock In \emph{Brazilian Symposium on Bioinformatics}. Springer, pp.
    50--57.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]